# Php MySql connection issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have db.php with the following code.

```
<?php
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "test";
$databaseLink = new mysqli ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);
if($databaseLink)
{
    mysqli_select_db($databaseLink,$dbName);
}
?>
```

which I usually import on to other php page like this

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/core/include/db.php";
?>
```

and works fine. I can start querying using `$databaseLink`. But there is one page where its not working. But if I explicitly define the connection like this `$databaseLink= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "test");` it works. There are other php files in the same directory which has no issues.

I have tried

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/core/include/db.php";
global($databaseLink);
?>
```

But that does not seem to work too. I have looked it up online for examples but can find any help.

Comment: You need to `require $path;` (or better yet `require_once` )

Comment: Are you sure the path is still the same and correct every time you use it? Plus, why not use `require_once $pathtodb` instead?

Comment: `include_once($path);`or `require_once($path)`

Comment: Using the global keyword is bad practice though

Comment: @Akintunde007 it's also not necessary here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to require your `db.php` file

```
require_once($path);
```

Comment: OP's method of initializing the database connection is perfectly valid

Comment: Thanks this Works. But cant I do without that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use include at the top of your php code to link in another php page.

```
include '/core/include/db.php';
```